# Do I have to repeat all dependencies in the test configuration?

Tags: haskell, cabal

This bugs me time and again, basically if I create a `test-suite` in the cabal configuration I add the projects `src` folder to the test suites `hs-source-dirs` section and repeat all dependencies in `build-depends`. A typical project might look like:

```
-- in file "foo.cabal"
library
  build-depends: a, b, c
  exposed-modules: Foo, Bar
  hs-source-dirs: src

test-suite tests
  build-depends: foo, a, b, c
  hs-source-dirs: test
```

The other option is to include `src` in the test suites `hs-source-dirs` as well.

Both of them require me to specify all build dependencies in the test case, as far as I know. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I would have thought that if you `build-depend` on `foo`, you only need those build-dependencies that are actually used by the tests in `test/`, which may be less.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I don't think it works that way. I just had to add all dependencies to a test-suite, prompting this question.

Comment: I too think that it should work - there was [this issue with `cabal repl` though](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2032)

Comment: @CarstenKönig possibly i am running into that. Do you want to create an answer from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as is but there is a [reported bug](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2032) when you use it with `cabal repl`

Overall it seems work with `cabal test` but if you try to load the test-file into `cabal repl` you might get an error like this:

```
Could not find module ‘XYZ’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘XZY-[ver]’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘XYZ’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

So right now it might be a good idea to indeed copy the dependencies but hopefully this will get resolved shortly